# Strange error when plotting values on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im using the following data.frame

```
x <- c(36.63, 41.99, 41.96)
y <- c(-91.69, -87.93, -87.91)
z <- c(14, 2, 3)

locationCrimes <- data.frame(long = x, lat = y, Frequency = z)
```

What I would like to do now is plot the data on the map of Chicago. So therefore I do:

```
library(ggmap)
chicago <- get_map(location = 'chicago', zoom = 11)
```

And try to plot it using:

```
ggmap(chicago) + geom_tile(data = locationCrimes, aes(x = long, y = lat, alpha = Frequency),
+                            fill = 'red') + theme(axis.title.y =  element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

But this gives me the following warnings:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_tile).
```

Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Comment: There's a stray `+` in there right under the `ggmap` code.

Comment: @cory: ggmap(chicago) + geom_tile(data = locationCrimes, aes(x = long, y = lat, alpha = Frequency),fill = 'red') + theme(axis.title.y =  element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank()) this gives me the same error

Comment: your latitude in locationCrimes  does not fit in your map

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error. Just warnings about the data not fitting the map.

Comment: Reinstalling ggmap did the trick